# Desktop application needs focus when user is in metro

Tags: c++, windows, microsoft-metro, focus

I have a desktop application (non metro). I need to get the user back to my application Desktop in some emergency situations (could mean life or death). How do I get focus back onto my application if the user is in a metro style application?

Comment: Upvoted, but if you're being literal about the "life or death" part you should perhaps reconsider using Windows as your operating system.  There are special-purpose operating systems out there (like the one used on the Mars Rover) that might be better suited.  FWIW, have you tried CreateDesktop/SwitchDesktop?

Comment: If your application makes life-or-death decisions, you probably shouldn't be running on the same machine where the user can play Angry Birds.

Comment: Unfortunately the operating system used it out of my control. Because this is essentially for notifying the masses. I already use some create desktop magic. But in some cases it is preferable to simply bring the user back to the desktop view so he can interact with other applications. Could I force a minimize or something of that sort?

Answer (score 1):

Found this great sample code on MSDN.

It checks to see if the windows 8 start screen is visible or not.  Check it out.

```
PCWSTR const _GetMonitorAppVisibilityString(MONITOR_APP_VISIBILITY monitorAppVisibility)
{
    PCWSTR pszAppVisibilityString = nullptr;
    switch (monitorAppVisibility)
    {
        case MAV_NO_APP_VISIBLE:
            pszAppVisibilityString = L"no apps visible";
            break;

        case MAV_APP_VISIBLE:
            pszAppVisibilityString = L"a visible app";
            break;

        case MAV_UNKNOWN:
        __fallthrough;
        default:
            pszAppVisibilityString = L"unknown";
            break;
    }
    return pszAppVisibilityString;
}
```

Follow this link to download the full sample c++ code (Visual C++ 2012/13):
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Start-screen-visibility-b1a72059